# MCMC for model with cumulative hazard involving integrals?

Tags: bayesian, survival, markov-chain-montecarlo, censoring, intractable-likelihood

Let $h(t\vert \theta, x)$ be a hazard function with parameter vector $\theta$ and covariate vector $x$, and let $H(t\vert \theta, x) = \int_0^t h(s\vert \theta, x)ds$ be the corresponding cumulative hazard function. Let also $\pi(\theta)$ denote the corresponding prior distribution. Suppose that $H(t\vert \theta, x)$ is not available in closed form, and can only be evaluated using numerical integration. The posterior distribution is

$$\pi(\theta\vert T,X) \propto \pi(\theta)\prod_{j=1}^n h(t_j\vert\theta,x_j)^{\delta_j} \exp[-H(t_j\vert\theta,x_j)],$$

where $T=(t_1,...,t_n)$, $X$ is the design matrix, and $\delta_j$ is the right-censoring indicator (1-dead, 0-alive).

Is there a trick to sample from this posterior distribution **without** using numerical integration to evaluate this function at each MCMC iteration?

Comment: If you have the survival function $S(t|\theta,x)$ or the cumulative distribution function $F(t|\theta,x)=1-S$ in closed form, then you can use those instead of the $\exp(-H\ldots)$ term. But I assume you do not have those, either? Numeric integration can be a bit painful, but at least in PROC MCMC within SAS or Stan (can be used from R, python etc.) there are decent(-ish) solutions for doing it.

Comment: @Björn Unfortunately, I don't have it. Since $S(t)= \exp[-H(t)]$ and $H(t)=-\log S(t)$, and $H$ is not available in closed form, it means that $S$ is not available. Indeed, I was thinking of using numerical integration, but in my case $n \approx 50,000$, so it would be nice to avoid it.